# How do I display a multidimensional array from a json api in wordpress?

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create either a list or table of fixtures for sports teams in a Wordpress website using data that comes in from a json api and I am running into issues figuring out exactly how to do this. As some of the fixtures have the same dates, I thought to group the data into a new array by doing the following:

```
$matchLists = json_decode(json_encode($fixture_data), True);

$newlist = array();
foreach ($matchLists as $key => $matchitem) {
  if (array_key_exists('matchDate', $matchitem)) {
    $newlist[$matchitem['matchDate']][$key] = ($matchitem);
 }
}
```

But this seems to have the effect of creating a further level to the array please see picture attached to see what the $newlist looks like: [newlist array example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeH04.png)

I am struggling to use the tutorials/examples I have seen so far on dealing with multi dimensional arrays to split this information out correctly. I can get the fixture date headings using:

```
 foreach($newlist as $key => $value)
     {
      $fixtureDate = date('D j M Y ga', strtotime($key));

$return .= '<li><h4>' . $fixtureDate . $test . '</h4></li>';
}
```

but this doesn't then offer me a route to pull out the rest of the data that I need.
This is how I got the information before realizing that I would need to group the fixtures into the correct dates/times

```
    $fixtureHome = json_decode(json_encode($fixtureitem->homeTeam), true);
    $fixtureAway = json_decode(json_encode($fixtureitem->awayTeam), true);
    $fixtureHomeName = $fixtureHome['name']; 
    $fixtureAwayName = $fixtureAway['name'];
    $fixtureHomeID = $fixtureHome['id'];
    $fixtureAwayID = $fixtureAway['id'];
    $fixtureID = $fixtureitem->id;
    $matchDate = $fixtureitem->matchDate;
    $fixtureDate = date('D j M Y ga', strtotime($matchDate));
    $homeColour = $fixtureHome['color'];
    $awayColour = $fixtureHome['color'];
    $fixtureStatus = json_decode(json_encode($fixtureitem->matchStatus), true);
    $scoreHome = $fixtureStatus['homeTeamScore'];
    $scoreAway = $fixtureStatus['awayTeamScore'];
```

but I don't understand how to achieve the same results now with the $newlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was just having problems figuring out how to access the correct levels...

```
            $fixtureHome = $fixtureitem['homeTeam']['name'];
            $fixtureAway = $fixtureitem['awayTeam']['name'];
```

Just having a mental block,thanks for looking :-)